# Haxe Int to String

Tags: string, haxe

It seems AS3 has a `toString()` for the `Number` class. Is there an equivalent in Haxe? The only solution I could come up with for converting an `Int` to a `String` is a function like:

```
public function IntToString(i:Int):String {
    var strbuf:StringBuf = new StringBuf();
    strbuf.add(i);
    return strbuf.toString();
}
```

Is there a better method that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You don't usually need to manually convert an int to a string because the conversion is automatic.

```
var i = 1;
var s = "" + i; // s is now "1"
```

The "formal" way to convert any value to a string is to use [`Std.string()`](https://api.haxe.org/Std.html#string):

```
var s = Std.string(i);
```

You could also use [string interpolation](https://haxe.org/manual/lf-string-interpolation.html):

```
var s = '$i';
```

The function your wrote is fine but definitely overkilling.

Comment: Would it also be possible to convert the string back into an integer?

Comment: Sure thing: `var i = Std.parseInt(s);`